How do I add a constraint to a bone so it follows a vertex in another object?
See video: https://imgur.com/RLkOZZf
I'm trying to have this bone at the end of this "rope" mesh follow the very corner of the sail (the vertex). I want the bone to be constrained to the absolute position of that vertex the entire time the "sail" is rolled up. I used a "Child Of" bone constraint for the bone, but it didn't work quite well. How do I go about doing this? Thanks.


assign a new vertex group with value 1 to your chosen vertex and move your bone to your vertex in object mode
choose a child of constraint with your cloth object and your vertex group from 1 to your bone
you might have to click on set inverse/clear inverse to get the right position of the bone

result:


Thanks for replying. However, my bone is not a singular bone in an armature object, it's a specific bone within an armature with multiple bones. So I don't want to affect the entire armature object, just the one bone. Would I be able to use vertex groups on individual bone constraints instead? How can I do that? What else can I do to achieve this? Thanks.

this is (!) a single individual bone - i just was too lazy to add other bones. Of course this works with a single bone. Hint: Try it first before asking... ;)

I did try. I'm not sure what you mean by "move your bone to vertex in object mode" though. I want to move the specific bone, not entire armature. Also, can you elaborate for step 2 please. Are you saying to add child of constraint to the cloth object only? And then what do I set as target there? If you could screenshot/record this step that would be great.

then provide your blend file with your "try" and we can tell you what you did wrong.
